# Fast Reports Two Parameters on a field

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

1.Setup:

Delphi 7, Fast Reports 4, SQLServerExpress 2008

2.Problem:

Have a TFRXQuery in a fastreports template that is of the format;

```
Select * from MyTable where Field1 >= '' and Field1 <= 'ZZZZ'
```

- Field1 is a text field
- By passing the above parameters, I expect all the records to be returned but, 
  fastreports is only returning the first record

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where do you expect to see it? You've given no information about the report itself, which is where the problem would be located. Have you checked the FR demos and documentation (which has some tutorials and examples that are very useful).

Comment: Missing binding of the (master)band to the dataset?